# How to use entityQuery to find nodes with a specific multi-value field containing one specific value (and no others)?

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have a node type "group" with an entity reference field "field_things" that can reference zero or more "thing" nodes. I'd like to use entityQuery to find all "groups" that have exactly one value for field_things, and that value is a specific "thing".

I can't tell from the docs how to combine those two requirements.

Comment: You can't. EQ does not supprot expressions which you'd need for counting deltas. You have to use standard query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it appears `entityQuery()` can't do this, but `entityQueryAggregate()` can. Below is an example that achieves the goal of the original post:

```
$thing_id = 101;
$q = \Drupal::entityQueryAggregate('node')
  ->condition('type', 'group')
  ->condition('field_things', $thing_id)
  ->groupBy('nid')
  ->conditionAggregate('field_things', 'COUNT', 1);
$res = $q->execute();
```

Running `dpm($res)` will show:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [nid] => 85
      [field_things_count] => 1
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
      [nid] => 33
      [field_things_count] => 1
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
      [nid] => 57
      [field_things_count] => 1
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
      [nid] => 54
      [field_things_count] => 1
    )
)
```